# maximize the value of a function using a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, maximize

I'm a bit new to R and I'm trying to maximize a simple value function, for a given parameter space.
The idea is to solve for c given different values of a.
The function is

```
 2*(c^2)-(7.8*c)-(4*c*a)+(5*a)+(a^2)+6=0
```

And I would like to solve for the different values of c, given values of a from 0 to 100.

Is there any way to do this simply using a for loop?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Provided I understood correctly, this can be easily solved analytically (completing the square). Why not do this instead of tuning some numerical method?

Comment: Because this is a parameter space for which I want to get the maximum, and I would like to avoid doing it by hand

Comment: *"Because this is a parameter space for which I want to get the maximum"* I don't think I understand. From what I read, you're trying to find the root of the given polynomial equation. I don't see any max/min optimisation. Solving the equation for c by hand is straightforward/trivial and much easier than tuning numerical root finders (like `polyroot`, or `pracma::bisect`).

Comment: a is a parameter space, and I want to know the values of c for different values of a

Comment: Just solve the equation for c (use Wolfram Alpha if you don't want to do it by hand), then plug in different values for a and Bob's your uncle. I don't see what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

The equation can be solved analytically for `c` (since it's a simple degree 2 polynomial equation). Using e.g. Wolfram Alpha gives the two solutions

[image]

We can roll this up into a function to calculate `c` for different `a`

```r
func_c <- function(a) a + 1/20 * (39 + c(-1, 1) * sqrt(200 * a^2 + 560 * a + 321))
sapply(0:10, func_c)
#         [,1]     [,2]    [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]      [,7]      [,8]      [,9]     [,10] [,11]
#[1,] 1.054176 1.306072 1.58304 1.867387 2.154937  2.44417  2.734398  3.025264  3.316562  3.608168   3.9
#[2,] 2.845824 4.593928 6.31696 8.032613 9.745063 11.45583 13.165602 14.874736 16.583438 18.291832  20.0
```

If you *must* use a numerical root finder (**and I don't recommend doing this here since this has a simple closed-form analytical solution**) you can use `polyroot`. The coefficients can be read off from the equation you give

```r
pol_coef <- function(a) c(5 * a + a^2 + 6, 7.8 + 4 * a, 2)
sapply(0:10, \(x) abs(polyroot(pol_coef(x))))
#         [,1]     [,2]    [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]      [,7]      [,8]      [,9]     [,10] [,11]
#[1,] 1.054176 1.306072 1.58304 1.867387 2.154937  2.44417  2.734398  3.025264  3.316562  3.608168   3.9
#[2,] 2.845824 4.593928 6.31696 8.032613 9.745063 11.45583 13.165602 14.874736 16.583438 18.291832  20.0
```

Solutions from both approaches are identical.